# Question about the definition of differentiability of a map between surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

In his book on Curves and Surfaces, Do Carmo defines what a differentiable map between surfaces means as follows:

> A continuous map $\varphi:V_1 \subset S_1 \to S_2$ of an open set $V_1$ of a regular surface $S_1$ to a regular surface $S_2$ is said to be *differentiable* at $p \in V_1$ if, given parametrizations
> $$\mathbf{x}_1: U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_1, \quad \mathbf{x}_2: U_2\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_2$$
> with $p \in \mathbf{x}_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_1(U_1))\subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2),$ the map $$\mathbf{x}_2^{-1}\circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1:U_1 \to U_2$$
> is differentiable at $q=\mathbf{x}_1^{-1}(p).$

My question is the following: Why do we need to assume that $\varphi$ is a continuous map? If we remove that word from the definition, is there an example of a map $\varphi: S_1 \to S_2$ between surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ that satisfies this new definition but that is not continuous?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Continuity is necessary for differentiability, just as in beginning calculus.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes. But when you define a differentiable function on elementary calculus, you don't assume first that your function is continuous in order to define differentiability, but prove it as a consequence. Here, DoCarmo is assuming it first

Comment: It is to ensure that you can write the map in local coordinates.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Isn't possible to deduce the continuity from the differentiability with this new definition?

Comment: @MoisheKohan But isn’t it possible to write any map in local coordinates?

Comment: @IvinBabu: Not if you want the domain of the composition $x_2^{-1}\circ \phi \circ x_1$ to be open (which is what one usually requires when "writing in local coordinates").  Yes, this is not an insurmountable problem, but there are easy examples showing that with such generalized notion of differentiability, it does not imply, say, continuity. And then what?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you please provide such a counterexample? I cannot figure it out one of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard multivariable calculus we consider functions $g : U \to V$ between open subsets $U \subset \mathbb  R^m$ and $V \subset \mathbb  R^n$. In fact, one can easily see that differentiability in $x \in U$ implies continuity in $x$.

do Carmo defines the concept of differentiability of a function $\varphi : V \to S_2$ by reducing it to the differentiability of the functions $\mathbf{x}_2^{-1}\circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1:U_1 \to U_2$ in the multivariable sense. In my opinion is not absolutely clear what he means by

> given parametrizations
> $$\mathbf{x}_1: U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_1, \quad \mathbf{x}_2: U_2\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_2$$
> with $p \in \mathbf{x}_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_1(U_1))\subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2)$.

Does he mean that we have to consider **some** such pair of parametrizations of **all** such pairs? Anyway, one can show that this does not really matter. In fact, do Carmo writes

> The proof that this definiton does not depend on the choice of parametrizations is left as an exercise.

Whatever the "correct" interpretation of the definition may be, the continuity of $\varphi$ at $p$ is needed to assure *the existence* of a pair of parametrizations such that $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_1(U_1))\subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2)$. Note that $p \in \mathbf{x}_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_1(U_1))\subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2)$ is only possible if $\varphi(p) \in \mathbf{x}_2(U_2)$. That is, the minimal requirement is that we take parameterizations $\mathbf{x}_1$ around $p \in S_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ around $\varphi(p) \in S_2$.

We can of course always consider the subset $\varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_2(U_2)) \subset S_1$, but if $\varphi$ is not continuous at $p$, then we cannot be sure that $\varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_2(U_2))$ is an open neigborhood of $p$ in $S_1$. It is even possible that $\varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_2(U_2)) = \{p\}$. Thus there may not exist a parameterization $\mathbf{x}_1$ around $p \in S_1$ such that $\mathbf{x}_1(U_1) \subset \varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_2(U_2))$ which is the same as  $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_1(U_1))\subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2)$.

You should compare this with Definition 1 on p. 72. Here do Carmo considers functions (no continuity assumption!) $f: V \to \mathbb R$ and defines differentiability via a parameterization around $p$. Continuity is not required here because $f$ maps each open neigborhood of $p$ in $S$ to $\mathbb R$. It is easy to see that differentiability implies continuity in this case.

**Update:**

Here is an example of "poor behavior" of non-continuous maps.

Take $S_1 = U \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb R^3$ with $U = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ and $S_2 = S^2$ = unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$. Define
$$\varphi: S_1 \to S_2, \varphi(x,y, 0) = \begin{cases} (x,y, \sqrt{1 - x^2-y^2}) & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\ (0,0,-1) & (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$$
Consider the point $p = (0,0,0) \in S_1$. Around $\varphi(p)$ we take do Carmo's parameterization $\mathbf{x_2} : U \to \mathbb R^3$ defined on p.56. Then $\varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_2(U)) = \{p\}$ and therefore no parameterization  $\mathbf{x_1} : U_1 \to \mathbb R^3$ of $S_1$ around $p$ has the property $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_1(U_1))\subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2)$. You can nevertheless consider the function $\mathbf{x}_2^{-1}\circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1$, but its domain is only $\{(0,0)\}$. It does not make sense to call such a function differentiable at $q = (0,0)$.

Comment: But what if we don't assume the continuity of $\varphi$?, is there an example of a map $\varphi$ that is not continuous but satisfies the remaining conditions of the definition? (Notice that if we cannot find such an example, then we should be able to deduce the continuity from the remaining conditions of the definition)

Comment: In my answer I explained that for non-continuous $f$ we may not be able to find  parameterizations as required in the definition. As an example take $S_1 = S_2 = S^2$ = unit sphere and $\varphi(x) = x$ for $x \ne (0,0,1)$ = north pole and $\varphi (0,0,1) = (0,0,-1)$ = south pole. Now let $p = (0,0,1)$. Consider the parameterization $\mathbf x_2$ as on p.56. We have $\varphi(p) \in \mathbf x_2(U)$. But $\varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_2(U)) = \mathbf{x}_2(U) \cup \{p\}$ and this set does not contain any open neighborhood of $p$. Thus there does not exist $\mathbf x_1$ as required in the definition.

Comment: Thank you. After thinking about your comments I have now revealed what's going on

Comment: After thinking about the definition again, I think that we can actually deduce the continuity from the definition of differentiability of $\varphi$ (omiting the word continuous from that definition, of course) on the following way: Since, by definition, we have that $\hat{varphi}=\mathbf{x}_2^{-1} \circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1$ is differentiable at $q=\mathbf{x}_1^{-1}(p)$ in the usual sense, then it is continuous at $q$. Now observe that $\varphi=\mathbb{x}_2 \circ \hat{\varphi}\circ \mathbf{x}_1^{-1}$ is continuous at $p$ being compositions of continuous maps

Comment: Note that one can argue that "we dont know if the parametrizations $\mathbf{x}_1$  and $\mathbf{x}_2$ satisfies the contidition $\varphi(\mathbf{x}_1(U_1)) \subset \mathbf{x}_2$ in order to compose $\mathbf{x}_2^{-1}\circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1$" but note that we are already asking for that condition in the definition of differentiability

Comment: After all, I think that the word "continuity" on the definition is superflous since we can deduce it from the rest of conditions on the actual definition

Comment: @rowcol I suggest that you write an own answer to properly explain your thoughts.

Comment: I just post it. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

As Paul explained, without continuity, there is no way to guarantee that the domain of the composition $\psi=x_2^{-1}\circ \phi \circ x_1$ is open in $R^2$. Of course, one can generalize the definition of a differentiable map so that the domain of the map need not be open:

Given a subset $E\subset {\mathbb R}^n$, a function $f: E\to {\mathbb R}^m$ and a point $p\in E$, one says that $f$ is differentiable at $p$ if there exists a linear map $L: {\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}^m$, such that
$$
f(x)=f(p) + L(x-p) + \eta(x),
$$
where $\eta(x)=o(|x-p|)$ as $x\to p$ in $E$.

However, this definition is always satisfied if $p$ is an isolated point in $E$, which leads to trouble and, when defining differentiability, one normally assumes that this is not the case. In your situation, there is no way to guarantee that the domain of $\psi$ has no isolated points (if you do not assume continuity of $\phi$). Here is another troublesome example:

Consider $S_1={\mathbb R}^2$ and $S_2= {\mathbb R}^2\times \{0, 1\}$ (two copies of the plane). Consider the discontinuous function $\phi: S_1\to S_2$,
$$
\phi(x,y)= (x,y)\times \{0\}
$$
if $(x,y)\in {\mathbb Q}^2$ and
$$
\phi(x,y)= (x,y)\times \{1\}
$$
if $(x,y)\notin {\mathbb Q}^2$.

Take the identity map as the parameterization of $S_1$.
Choose the two "obvious" charts on $S_2$,  which are
$$
\varphi_0: (x,y)\times \{0\}\mapsto (x,y) 
$$
$$
\varphi_1: (x,y)\times \{1\}\mapsto (x,y). 
$$
Then the compositions $\varphi_i\circ \phi$ are both  differentiable everywhere in the sense of the above definition.  However, $\phi$ is discontinuous.

By tinkering further with the definitions, one can eliminate such examples, but why bother? It is much easier to require continuity of the map to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this question, I concluded that the word "continuous" on the original definition may be omitted. In other words, I propose the following new definition that differs on the original one only at the word "continuous":

> **Definition 1.** A map $\varphi:V_1 \subset S_1 \to S_2$ of an open set $V_1$ of a regular surface $S_1$ to a regular surface $S_2$ is said to be *differentiable* at $p \in V_1$ if, given parametrizations $$\mathbf{x}_1:U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_1, \quad \mathbf{x}_2:U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_2$$
> with $p \in \mathbf{x}_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x_1}(U_1)) \subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2),$ the map $$\mathbf{x}_2^{-1}\circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1 : U_1 \to U_2$$ is differentiable at $q=\mathbf{x}_1^{-1}(p)$.

Now I assert that we can deduce at least the continuity of $\varphi$ at $p$ from this new definition. That is,

> **Proposition**
> Let $\varphi: V_1 \subset S_1 \to S_2$ a map between regular surfaces defined on an open set $V_1$ of $S_1$.If $p \in V_1$  and $\varphi$ is differentiable (in the sense of Def. 1) at $p$, then $\varphi$ is continuous at $p$.

**Proof**. By the Definition 1, we can choose parametrizations $$\mathbf{x}_1:U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_1, \quad \mathbf{x}_2:U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_2$$
with $p \in \mathbf{x}_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x_1}(U_1)) \subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2),$ such that the map $$\bar{\varphi}=\mathbf{x}_2^{-1}\circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1 : U_1 \to U_2$$ is differentiable at $q=\mathbf{x}_1^{-1}(p)$.

Observe that by the conditions given in Def 1., we can actually compose $\mathbf{x}_2^{-1}\circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1$ without any problem. Since $\bar{\varphi}$ is differentiable (in the usual sense) at $q$, then it is continuous at $q$. And hence, the map $\mathbf{x}_2\circ \bar{\varphi} \circ \mathbf{x}_1^{-1}$ is continuous at $p$. Furthermore, $$\varphi|_{\mathbf{x}_1(U_1)}=\mathbf{x}_2\circ \bar{\varphi} \circ \mathbf{x}_1^{-1}.$$

Hence, $\varphi|_{\mathbf{x}_1(U_1)}$ is continuous at $p$. But, since $\mathbf{x}_1(U_1)$ is an open subset of $S_1$, then, in fact, $\varphi$ is continuous at $p$. The proposition follows. $\blacksquare$

Observe that the previous proposition shows the continuity of $\varphi$ at $p$, but not the continuity of $\varphi$ over all $V_1,$ as the original definition requires. This procedure actually guarantees that $\varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_2(U_2))$ contains an open neighbourhood of $p$ at $S_1$ since $\varphi$ is continuous at $p$ and $\varphi(p) \in \mathbf{x}_2(U_2).$ This makes me think that we don't actually need to assume continuity on the original definition. Am I right?

Comment: In your definition you have again the somewhat unclear "given". I suggest "... *differentiable* at $p \in V_1$ if **there exist** parametrizations $$\mathbf{x}_1:U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_1, \quad \mathbf{x}_2:U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_2$$
with $p \in \mathbf{x}_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi(\mathbf{x_1}(U_1)) \subset \mathbf{x}_2(U_2),$ such that the map $$\mathbf{x}_2^{-1}\circ \varphi \circ \mathbf{x}_1 : U_1 \to U_2$$ is differentiable at $q=\mathbf{x}_1^{-1}(p)$."